# What to do with a dataset that shows NULL in all variables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, null

I recently used BigQuery and downloaded a dataset. While previewing the dataset all of the rows were NULL. No numbers/integers NOTHING. What can I do in this situation?

I try to run the query as I was doing a coursera course but it lead to no results.

Comment: Could you show the query?

Comment: What does "downloaded a dataset" mean? You exported a table? If so, how? And what does "previewing the dataset" mean? You look at the exported table with an editor? But what then does "I try to run the query" mean? That rather sounds like you didn't download anything, but ran a query on the database instead. And "all of the rows were NULL" means you see many rows, but all values in those rows are empty?

Comment: Tips on how to ask a question: basics: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and for more info:  http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ (take particular note of "**Sample Code and Data**")